# Utility to check Windows NTFS ACL/ACE dependency integrity

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

I'm having issues with imaging a NTFS filesystem where the ACL/ACE of a file has invalid ACL/ACE dependencies. `chkdsk` does not detect or fix the problem. Is there a tool available to detect (fixing is optional but preferred) such issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `icacls.exe` utility has a `/verify` switch that checks for issues with your ACLs. The two things it checks are that the ACL is in "canonical form" and that the ACL length is consistent with the ACE count. I'm assuming the "canonical form" check would catch your problem.

It won't automatically repair as far as I know, but you might be able to do some scripting to save the broken filenames off to a file, then re-run icacls against them to repair.

icacls ships with 2003SP2+ by the way.

[icacls reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/403edfcc-328a-479d-b641-80c290ccf73e.aspx)

Comment: I'll try this tonight and see if it picks up the issue. Thank you.